# Is David Sheridan fully human?

Tags: babylon-5

In the finale of *Babylon 5*, we find out that John Sheridan and Delenn have a child named David, but unfortunately we never see him on screen. Given that Delenn is half-Minbari and half-Human, is David fully human? Or is he quarter-Minbari?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the tie-in novel [Out of the Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_Legions_of_Fire_%E2%80%93_Out_of_the_Darkness), he's a quarter-Minbari but *appears entirely human.* Minbari women seem to find him physically appealing but largely because of his self-confidence and general attractiveness.

> *On the other hand, when faced with studies, David consistently rose to
>   the occasion with such facility that his teachers wondered just how
>   much he could accomplish if he applied himself fully.*
>
> ***Outwardly he appeared Human.*** The color of his hair had shifted over
>   time. He had gone from being towheaded to dark-haired, and he tended
>   to wear it long. This annoyed his father, whose old military instincts
>   kicked in. Every so often, he would extol the virtues of a short
>   haircut, but David seemed to pay such critiques no mind. Curiously,
>   his eyebrows retained their light color, but the dark eyes beneath
>   remained evocative of his mother.
>
> *He did, however, possess his father's charisma. That much was
>   unmistakable. Nor was his charisma limited to its effects on Humans;
>   Minbari women - grown women - would do double takes when he passed,
>   looking him up and down appreciatively while he winked at them or came
>   up with some bon mot that always prompted gentle laughter or looks of
>   amusement.*

As to why he wasn't seen in the show, JMS spoke to this in the audio commentary for [B5: Sleeping in Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_in_Light).

> *"The other problem being that I didn't want to show David yet. **And
>   he would be a mix of Minbari and Human and I hadn't worked out quite
>   the look that I wanted for that yet.** I also didn't want to lock us
>   into an actor in case we see that person down the road."*

Comment: "Yet"? Wasn't that the last episode?

Comment: @colmde - There were multiple spin-offs; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusade_(TV_series), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_The_Legend_of_the_Rangers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_The_Lost_Tales